# Разложить массив по суммам чисел

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, любой-язык

Есть массив наподобие `x = {21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,27};`, надо его упаковать по суммам.
То что есть пока еще не годно, все еще брутфорсю=)

```
//частоты (для [0,0,2,2] - [2,0,2])
inline auto e(std::vector<int>& z, int sz)
{
    std::vector<int> c(sz, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++)
        c[z[i]]++;
    return c;
}
inline void f(std::vector<int>& x, std::vector<int>& c, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& res, int ln)
{
#define n 4
    int sz = x.size();
    int d = std::pow(sz, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int j = i;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, j /= sz)
            sum += x[j % sz];
        if (sum == ln)
        {
            std::vector<int> _res(n); // добавил n
            int j = i;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, j /= sz)
                _res[i] = j % sz;
            auto d = e(_res, sz);// count
            int err = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
                if (d[i] > c[i])
                    err++;
            if (!err) // пропустить те на которые нету
            {
                std::sort(_res.begin(), _res.end());
                res.push_back(_res);
            }
        }
    }
    std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
    auto it = std::unique(res.begin(), res.end());
    res.erase(it, res.end());
}
size_t best = -1;
int g(std::vector<int>& x, std::vector<int>& c, std::vector<int> parent, int depth, int ln)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
    f(x, c, res, ln);
    std::random_shuffle(res.begin(), res.end()); // для разнообразия =)
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
    {
        auto y = x, d = c; // для каждого решения от f создается новые
   // массивы с обновленной информацией
        for (auto& z : res[i])
            d[z]--;
        for (int j = 0; j < d.size();)
        {
            if (!d[j])
            {
                y.erase(y.begin() + j);
                d.erase(d.begin() + j);
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
        auto _parent = parent; // результаты передаются выше,
    // здесь parent - уже не нужно
        for (auto& z : res[i])
            _parent.push_back(x[z]);
        _parent.push_back(-1);
        g(y, d, _parent, depth + 1, ln);
    }
/// print -->
    int tail = 0, sum = 0, i = 0, l = 0;
    for (auto& z : c)
        tail += z;
    if (best > tail)
    {
        best = tail, std::cout << "\ndepth = " << depth << ", tail = " << tail << '\n';
        for (auto& z : parent)
        {
            if (z == -1)
                std::cout << " = " << sum << std::endl, sum = i = 0, l++;
            else
            {
                if (!i++)
                    std::cout << l << ": ";
                std::cout << z << '+', sum += z;
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
            while (c[i]--)
                std::cout << x[i] << '+';
    }
    return tail;
}
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> c(x.back() - x.front() + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        c[x[i] - x.front()]++;
    auto it = std::unique(x.begin(), x.end());
    x.erase(it, x.end());
    std::vector<int> res;
    g(x, c, res, 0, strtoul(argv[1], 0, 10));
}
```

Как работает:

- функция f находит все сочетания (ограничения длины не должно быть, здесь 4), их (кол-во типов)^4, выбираются те сочетания, которые дают нужную сумму;
- при помощи g выбираются следующие сочетания, и идет продвижение до того как не будет возможности собрать нужную сумму;
- число 95 может быть другим, если вариант получится лучше

Основные сложности с тем как передать информацию дальше - я использую вектор parent чтобы передавать, не очень удачно.
Судя по 1-му восхождению на вершину - дебагал размер 95 - вариантов 66`520`453`480`448`000`000`000
 (=16*11*11*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*4*4*4*4* 4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*1*..)

Решение с хвостом 8 (45 по 118 и 2 по 101):

```
21+21+23+26+27
21+21+24+26+26
21+22+25+25+25
21+23+24+25+25
21+22+25+25+25
21+24+24+24+25
21+24+24+24+25
21+24+24+24+25
21+24+24+24+25
21+22+25+25+25
21+22+25+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+22+24+25+25
22+23+23+25+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+23+24+25
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
23+23+24+24+24
25+25+25+26
25+25+25+26
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @VladD уже читал, у меня получается много рюкзаков, это еще сложнее?, все-таки ищу на практике, теорию не смогу перенести. Здесь что-то похожее есть, про (какой-то) гольф), там решение в строку, отличия... небольшие?

Comment: Решение в строку по количеству текста, но это полный перебор, так что эта одна строка будет считать довольно долго.

Comment: Сумма на 95 не делится. Это нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, там хвост отстанется, в идеале один. находит группу оно очень быстро, непонятно что дальше. идет умножение 15*10*5... 200+раз. и еще оптимально/неопт. выбрать сумму (95)

Comment: а конечная цель то какая? как можно больше по суммам раскидать? Или как?

Comment: @pavel чтобы остаток маленький был, сумму можно подбирать чтобы было по 4 в ряд или 5(3)...

Answer (score 3):

Ну самое простое что приходит в голову - это подсчитать одинаковые числа. Дальше так как у нас сумма остаётся не изменой, то и изменения чисел происходит симметрично например: a+b+c=d <=> (a+n)+(b-n)+c=d, то бишь надо выделить эту самую n из всех чисел.

Итого: 
`массив<КоличествоПовторений,n \\относительно одного(возможно выдуманного) числа>`

Comment: Плюс оптимизация всяких в процессе переборов - например не пробовать добавлять числа, которые больше (95 минус текущая сумма), максимальное кол-во использований числа опять же можно определить как 95/число

Comment: @markov  Не понятно что даст, код хотя бы нужен, теорию не осилю. Что значит не пробовать?, сама суть пробовать - больше - пропуск, и кол-во у меня просто 4 т.к невозможно пока что по-другому и тоже проверяется. Я еще попытають попрофилировать.

Comment: Есть идея что f будет выбирать одинаковые комбинации, если ничего кардинально не поменялось (кол-ва элементов хватает на все эти варианты), ничего не понятно..=( ,поможет отбросить длинную череду 4-5-ок

Comment: @J.Doe числа обязательно идут последовательно?

Comment: @АльбусПерсивальДамблдор это отсортированный, порядок не важен. Их можно потом местами поменять, они идентичные по размеру т.е

Answer (score 0):

## Подразделим эту задачу:

### 1. Найти возможные комбинации

```
 В нашем случае будем использовать дерево/структуру Node:
 int Parent;
 int value;
 int Nodes[];

 Общие данные:
 int variants[]; \\варианты подставляемых чисел, отсортированы по возрастанию
 int counts[]; \\количество одинаковых/повторяющихся вариантов
 int finish; \\число к которому стремимся/надо найти

 И рекурсивный метод:
 int Find(ushort part, Node nd)\\остаток которого не хватает до конечного числа & ветвь
 {
     for(int n = 0; n < variants[].Count; n++)
     {
         int temp = finish - variants[n];
         if(temp == 0)
         {
             \\Подходящий вариант
             nd.Nodes += new Node(){ value = variants[n]; parent nd; }.ToString()
         }
         else if(temp > variants[].First()) \\если ещё можно подставить числа
         {
             \\Надо углублять дерево
             Find(temp,
             new Node(){ value = variants[n]; parent = nd; }
             );
         }
     }
 }

 Метод превращающий структуру в текст:\\если лень самому придумывать
 string Node.ToString()
 {
     Node temp = this;
     while(Parent != null)
     {
        temp.value.ToString() + " ";\\Int32 в строку
        temp = Parent;
     }
 }
```

### 2. Совместить комбинации, чтоб не осталось лишних элементов в массиве

Comment: 2 завтра придумаю, сейчас уже мозги поплыли ))